# Pass instance of class into Class

Tags: c++, class

I need to pass a different instance of a class into that class so I can access in while inside

```
Player Player1(Player2);
Player Player2(Player1);
```

However because P2 hasn't been created yet it won't work. Or is there a better way to access P2 while inside P1?

Comment: Exactly. How would Player1 know about Player2, because it is NOT created by the time Player1 is created. Better to use a setter method inside the Player class.

Comment: You should split the code among source files (.cpp) and header files (.h). Then in header files you should **declare** the one class before the code **defining** the other. In source files you can do whatever you please with your Player objects instances.

Comment: I'll forewarn you, this has the distinct aroma of a bad design. There *must* be a constructor for `Player` that does *not* mandate a reference to another `Player`. Because if a reference to a `Player` is required in the only constructor of the `Player` class, you have to ask yourself where the first `Player` would *ever* come from.  @WojciechFrohmberg please elaborate on how you're planning on "splitting" the source of the *same class* among *two* header files. Perhaps you didn't notice, but there is only *one* class in that brief piece of code?

Comment: @WhozCraig I assumed the Player1 and Player2 are separate classes. In other case it is imposible to create two differenct constructors taking the same parameter type...

Comment: You need to declare them before calling `Player1`  in `Player2` and vice versa. Please make sure you use `copy constructor` to this or both your objects will be referring to the same memory location which could lead to runtime problems.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg yeah, it looked odd to me at first as well at first glance. `Player1` and `Player2` are actually the *variables*. `Player` is the only class.

Comment: @WhozCraig If they are variables then I don't really see what's the problem here...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg The OP's queston spells it out. He wants them to reference *each other* at construction time. I.e. one can't be constructed without the other already having *been* constructed, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. How would Player1 know about Player2, because it is NOT created by the time Player1 is created. Better to use a setter method inside the Player class.

Example would be.

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Player();

        setPlayer(Player* player)
        {
            otherPlayer = player;
        }
    private:
        Player* otherPlayer;
};
```

Then you can call these as.

```
Player Player1;
Player Player2;

Player1.setPlayer(&Player2);
Player2.setPlayer(&Player1);
```

Comment: Can't the same be achieved by using copy constructors instead of using setter methods.

Comment: Considering the way he creates the object, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the pointer in which Player2 will later be created:

```
/*** class declaration ***/
class Player
{
private:
  class Player **ref; // pointer to pointer of reference Player class
  bool all_done;      // flag to indicate whether the whole initialization procedure is finished
public:
  Player1(class **RefPtr);    // constructor declaration
  void DoRemainingInit();     // if necessary, perform remaining initialization steps
}
```

...

```
/*** class method definitions ***/
Player::Player(class **RefPtr):
    ref(NULL), all_done(false)
{
  // ...

  if (RefPtr == NULL)
  {
    // pointer invalid -> do some error handling here
    return;
  }

  ref = RefPtr;
  if (*ref == NULL)
  {
    // pointer is valid, but doesn't yet point to another class instance -> try to access it later by calling DoRemainingInit()
    // ...
  }
  else
  {
    // pointer is valid and should point to an existing object (depends on whether RefPtr was properly initialized with NULL outside) -> do your stuff here
    all_done = true;
    // ...
  }
}

void Player::DoRemainingInit()
{
  if (all_done)
  {
    // nothing to be done here -> return immediately
    return;
  }

  if (*ref == NULL)
  {
    // reference object not yet existent -> possibly treat as error?
    // ...
  }
  else
  {
    // reference object is now existent -> do the same stuff as in the constructor's "else" branch
    all_done = true;
    // ...
  }
}
```

...

```
/*** creating the objects ***/
class *Player1 = NULL;  // WARNING: MUST be set to NULL initially, otherwise the check inside Player's constructor won't work correctly
class *Player2 = NULL;  // WARNING: MUST be set to NULL initially, otherwise the check inside Player's constructor won't work correctly

Player1 = new Player(&Player2);
Player2 = new Player(&Player1);

Player1->DoRemainingInit();
Player2->DoRemainingInit();

return; // WARNING: "ref" inside both classes is not valid any more, once we return here!
```

Note that the "ref" attribute actually points to the "Player2" pointer itself and is hence no longer valid once the scope of the "Player2" pointer is left even inside the Playeyou can't Player2 inside the constructor of Player1 right away.
You may also want to restrict the access to the reference by making it constant.

Also note, that the code above is example code and hence lacking some basic safety checks (e.g. we don't know if "new" was able to actually create a class instance).